# Estimating $ f(N) = \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} H_{m-N}^{(1)}(x) J_m(y)$ when $N$ is large?

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, upper-lower-bounds

I want to find an estimate on the magnitude of the following function in terms of $x,y$ and $N$ when $N$ is large:
$$
f(N) = \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} H_{m-N}^{(1)}(x) J_m(y), \quad \quad (*)
$$
where $H_{m}^{(1)}$ is the Hankel function of the first kind of order $m$ and $J_m$ is the Bessel funtion of order $m$ and $x>y>0$.

I am used to estimating Hankel and Bessel functions when $m$ is large and we can use
\begin{align}
|J_m(x)| & \sim \sqrt{\frac{1}{2 \pi m}} \bigg(\frac{ex}{2m}\bigg)^m, \\
|H_m^{(1)}(x)| & \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi m}} \bigg(\frac{ex}{2m}\bigg)^{-m}.
\end{align}

In particular, this gives $|H_m^{(1)}(x)J_m(y)| \sim \frac{1}{m}\bigg(\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^m$ as $m \to \infty$.

However, it seems the above relations don't seem to be of any use for the more complicated expression $(*)$. Is there any way of getting an estimate on the function $f(N)$ as $N\to \infty$ or is this an impossible task?

Comment: Numerically it seems that it could be something close to $N^N \bigg(\frac{x}{y}\bigg)^N$, at least when $x=1$ and $y$ is around 10... but its hard to check as it increases so fast overflow issues prevent me from using a really large value of $N$ in Matlab. In any case I need an analytic estimate not a numeric one.

Comment: Your example $x=1,y\simeq 10$ seems to be in contradiction with the given condition $x>y>0$.

Comment: @PaulEnta Opps, I switched the places of $y$ and $x$ the second time in the second last paragraph compared to the equation $(*)$. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [parity formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.4)
 \begin{equation}
 H^{(1)}_{-n}\left(z\right)=(-1)^{n}{H^{(1)}_{n}}\left(z\right)\quad ; \quad J_{-n}\left(z\right)=(-1)^{n}J_{n}\left(z\right)
 \end{equation} 
 we can transform (*) as
 \begin{align}
 f(N) &= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} H_{m-N}^{(1)}(x) J_m(y)\\
 &= (-1)^N\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}} H_{N-m}^{(1)}(-x) J_{-m}(-y)\\
 &=(-1)^N\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} H_{N+k}^{(1)}(-x) J_{k}(-y)\\
 \end{align}
Using the [Neumann's addition theorem](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23.E2),
\begin{equation}
H^{(1)}_{\nu}\left(u- v\right)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}H^{(1)}_{\nu+ k}\left(u\right)J_{k}\left(v\right)
\end{equation} 
valid for $\left|u\right|>\left|v\right|$. 
Taking $u=-x,v=-y,\nu=N$ (and $x>y>0$) we obtain
\begin{equation}
f(N)=(-1)^NH^{(1)}_{N}\left(y-x\right)
\end{equation} 
The [asymptotic form](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.19.E2) for $N\to\infty$ is then
\begin{equation}
f(N)\sim (-1)^{N+1}\frac{i}{\sqrt{\pi}}2^{N+1/2}N^{N-1/2}e^{-N}\left( y-x \right)^{-N}
\end{equation}

Comment: I just checked it numerically, this is super accurate thanks! Its great to see this usage of Neumann's addition theorem too, I will have to remember that one for similar situations in the future.